# Is there available space images taken by the south pole Gregorian telescope?

Tags: telescope, space

I searched the internet for images taken by the [South Pole Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Pole_Telescope#The_telescope) but without successes in finding it.

Edit:Some images
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The South Pole Telescope (SPT) was funded, in part, by the NSF. This means their data must be made public as that is almost always a condition of funding by the NSF.

If you go to the SPT's homepage, they link to their [Data Management Policy](http://pole.uchicago.edu/spt/hep_summary_dmp/Summary%20for%20HEP%20of%20Data%20Management%20Principles%20(SPT).pdf). Within this policy they state:

> The collaboration – in particular the P.I. and data managers at the University of Chicago – bear the responsibility for making data public. Public data products are hosted on University of Chicago machines and on the NASA Legacy Archive for Microwave Background Data Analysis (LAMBDA) server.

I went over to NASA's LAMBDA server and found that SPT data was hosted [right here](https://lambda.gsfc.nasa.gov/product/spt/). Look to the left-hand side menu to see the links to raw data for the SPT-SZ and SPTpol instruments, individually.

The University of Chicago hosts their data [right here](http://%20pole.uchicago.edu/public/publications.html) (props to called2voyage). It seems that they provide publications and include any data used in that publication rather than just hosting all the RAW data like the LAMBDA server does. Use whichever is most convenient for you.

Comment: Here is the University of Chicago data release page: http://pole.uchicago.edu/public/publications.html